# Write DataTable to csv code break for loop

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I am trying to write a `DataTable` inside a for loop.
However, the write step seems break the for loop. The for loop is run only once.

How can I write the `.csv` file from `DataTable` without breaking the for loop?

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = listDataTable[dtIndex].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                      Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in listDataTable[dtIndex].Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }

    File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why you need for loop? You are not using `i` of for loop anywhere in the code.

Comment: Why would you have a call to `WriteAllText` inside the loop? Perhaps you should try debugging your code.

Comment: Can you explain your code? What is the purpose of the `for` loop? What are you trying to do 10 times?

Comment: Actually, I simplify the code from my code. I just try to show that the write file is run inside a for loop, and the for loop just run one times. Is that possible it is caused by exception occured in the write file?

Comment: *Is that possible it is caused by exception occured in the write file?* That is easy to check isn't it? Add `try-catch` and see.

Comment: How did you conclude that the loop runs just one time?